# Resize displayed images from instagram widget

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want to change the defaut size of the pictures displayed by an instagram widget [on the footer of my website](http://da-montanha.com) to 240x160px, this is my current css code:

```
#footer {
float: left;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(../images/footer-bg.png);
background-position: left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-color: #000;
padding: 50px 0 30px 0;
}
.instagram {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 35px 0;
}

.instagram h2 {
    color: #fff;
}
.instagram h2:before {
    content: '';
    display: none;
}
.instagram ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
.instagram ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    width: 197px;
    background: #fff;
}
.instagram ul li img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.instagram ul li:hover img {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.instagram ul li
{
width:205px !important;
}

.tagcloud {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

What are the correct changes that I should make in order to go from this:[image]

To This:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do some calculation and set `width` in `%`.

```
.instagram {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 35px 0;
}
.instagram ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    width: 12.5%;
    height: auto;
    background: #fff;
}

.widget.instagram img,
.instagram ul li img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
}
```

To avoid stretching images crop the images with same width and height.

Comment: Your solution work pretty well!!! Thank you! Also, can you help me with the padding? as you can see [here](http://da-montanha.com) the images don't have a space between the other elements!

Comment: Yes, But you used comma instead of semicolon.